# How to resolve "boto3/boto missing" errors in Ansible when accessing AWS modules

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ansible, boto3, boto

When running AWS modules like route53_info and ec2_group_info, I get json/boto3/boto errors like:

```
"json and boto/boto3 is required."
```

and

```
"boto3 required for this module"
```

I've verified that both boto and boto3 are installed by pip3 and "json" is apparently a core module and so doesn't need to be installed.

Environment:

Vagrant/VirtualBox VM running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

/usr/bin/python and /usr/bin/python2 are python v2.17.15+;
/usr/bin/python3 is python v3.6.9

/usr/bin/pip3 is v9.0.1 (which seems to be old but when I updated it, many things broke)

"pip3 list | grep boto" yields:
    boto (2.49.0)
    boto3 (1.10.29)
    botocore (1.13.29)

I'm baffled because it seems like parts of Ansible is using python2 and parts are using python3.  How does anyone debug things like this?

I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: My guess above (about parts of Ansible using python2 while other parts are using python3) turned out to be right.

I installed pip using python2, then installed boto and boto3.  The "boto ... required" message is gone.

Why is Ansible (or anyone) using python2 (recognizing that re-writing code is no easy task)?

Comment: [ansible autodiscovers python on the host by default](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html). If you don't want to rely on this mechanism, you can set the host_var`ansible_python_interpreter` to the path you want to use or tune the discovery method (see link). ansible will run with both python 2 and 3. This is independent from the python version used on the controller which will depend on how you installed ansible.

Comment: Further, I've gotten my configuration to the point where Python2 is no longer installed (under Ubuntu 18.04).  So anything that executes Python code will be executing /usr/bin/python3.

Comment: That is also a way to fix the problem :)

Comment: @Zeitounator, thank you for the pointer to that variable.